# ansible create a postgres user

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I'm using Ansible 1.9.1 under Debian 7 to a Debian 8.3 machine and when I go to create a new postgresql using with th efollowing syntax

```
- name: Create postgresql user
  postgresql_user: user={{ db_user }} password={{ db_passwd }} role_attr_flags=CREATEDB,SUPERUSER
  become_user: postgres
```

It just hangs there. The only way I get around this is to allow the postgres to have passwordless sudo access. This isn't the best idea and I would like to work out what is happening when it's just sitting there.

```
%sudo   ALL= (postgres) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is hanging at the password prompt. Call your playbook with the [`--ask-become-pass`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#new-command-line-options) option.